# Core Data and Concurrency

Tags: ios, json, firebase, core-data, swift3

I am using the `performBackgroundTask` function to pull data from firebase, compare it with data already stored in Core Data, save new data to Core Data, and call a completion handler when done.

I understand that Core Data is not thread safe but I am trying to do this concurrently.

```
static func cache(completion: @escaping (Void) -> Void) {
    CoreDataHelper.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        // fetch previously saved Core Data from main thread (1) and filter them (2)
        let newsSourceIDs = NewsSourceService.getSaved().filter{$0.isEnabled}.map{$0.id!}
        let oldArticleURLs = ArticleService.getSaved().map{$0.url!}
        // create firebase database reference
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        Constants.Settings.timeOptions.forEach { time in
            let timeRef = ref.child("time\(time)minutes")
            newsSourceIDs.forEach { newsSourceID in
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                // pull from Firebase Database
                timeRef.child(newsSourceID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        guard let newsSourceDict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String:String]] else {
                            return
                        }
                        newsSourceDict.values.forEach { articleDict in
                            dispatchGroup.enter()
                            if oldArticleURLs.contains(articleDict["url"]!) {
                                dispatchGroup.leave()
                                return
                            }
                            // create article entity with firebase data
                            let article = Article(context: context)
                            article.date = articleDict["date"]
                            article.source = newsSourceID
                            article.time = Int16(time)
                            article.title = articleDict["title"]
                            article.url = articleDict["url"]
                            article.urlToImage = articleDict["urlToImage"]
                            dispatchGroup.leave()
                        }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }
        }
        // when done, save and call completion handler (3)
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            do {
                try context.save()
                completion()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Fetch from Core Data function:

```
static func getSaved() -> [Article] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Article> = Article.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let results = try CoreDataHelper.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```

1. Can I fetch Core Data from the main thread during `performBackgroundTask`?
2. Should I filter with the high level `filter` function or using a special batch request (can I do that concurrently?)
3. How can I use `dispatchGroup.notify(queue:)` to determine when the creation and saving of Core Data is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I fetch Core Data from the main thread during performBackgroundTask?

You can **fetch** from any thread if you use that method. You can't use the results on the main thread though. `NSPersistentContainer` provides the `viewContext` property for use on the main thread.

> Should I filter with the high level filter function or using a special batch request (can I do that concurrently?)

I'd do it with a predicate on a normal non-batch request. Either of the ways you mention are possible. It depends on what kind of fetching and filtering you need. A batch request might be good if the fetch and filter takes a long time to run. Filtering the results after the fetch might be good if your filtering rules can't be expressed in a predicate.

> How can I use dispatchGroup.notify(queue:) to determine when the creation and saving of Core Data is complete?

Add the notify call after your `forEach` closure. If you never `enter`, it'll execute immediately. If you do `enter`, it will execute when you match each `enter` with a `leave`.

One other detail: Your `getSaved` method should take a managed object context as an argument, and fetch with that context. Otherwise you're mixing contexts here. The `performBackgroundTask` creates one context, but you're using a different one in `getSaved`.

Comment: does context.save() happen synchronously (or quick enough) that the completion handler will be able to access the data?

Comment: and which queue should notify use (not .main?)

Comment: Saving is synchronous. What queue to notify on depends on what the code in the notify block needs to do. If it's updating the UI, then the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle concurrency with Core Data(one of the easiest, but not optimized) would be using a "child" managedObjectContext with a concurrencyType of private, setting that new `MOC`'s parent to be the `MOC` on your main thread.

```
let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)

privateMOC.parent = persistentManager.managedObjectContext

privateMOC.perform {
    do {
        try privateMOC.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
    }
}
```

You would perform all of your needed core data actions inside of the `.perform` closure.  When you run `privateMOC.save()` the changes are pushed up to the parent managedObjectContext on the main thread.